# Use "Always Encrypted" enabled MS SQL Server data with NodeJS

Tags: sql-server, node.js, encryption, tedious

How can I implement MS SQL connection and CRUD operations with NodeJS (ExpressJS)?

I tried using [tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) by setting its `options.encrypt = true`. But still it returned encrypted data from my local dev server.

```
var config = {
  userName: 'sa',
  password: 'password',
  server: 'localhost',
  options: {
    database: 'Employees',
    encrypt: true
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any solution for this problem? I need to use Node and using always encryption SQL 2016 method.

Comment: faced same problem